# How to use VBA to Autofill a Row until the end of the number of data in another row

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I have a macro that fills a range (A2:B110) based on data that is available in column C. However column C is growing daily and my macro will fill only until B110.

How can I make this B110 as a variable based on column C size?

Currently this is my code:

```
Range("A2:B2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:B110")
Range("A2:B110").Select
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Find the last row and store it to a variable.

Comment: `Select` is a macro-recorder thing and is [best avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999). `Application.CutCopyMode = False` is irrelevant here. There may be a more efficient or easier way to fill the range than using `AutoFill`, so why don't you share the formulas in `A2:B2`? The most common way, probably the easiest, to get the last row in a column is by using something like `Dim lRow As Long: lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row`. Read about it in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920). Why don't you share the complete code and explain what it needs to do?

Comment: If Excel can find the range to fill without specific instruction in manual mode, why can't it when automating in VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.SpecialCells` Property. For instance,

```
Dim lcol As Long
lcol = Range("C:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
```

This finds the last cell with a value in Column C. Then, you can set the destination range like

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:B" & lcol)
```

Comment: Why are you finishing the code with Range("A2:B110").Select ?

Comment: It did not work.

Comment: @MarcoTerra typo. Edited accordingly. I can fix the code if you explain what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Range("A2:B2").Select
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:B"&CStr(LastRow))
Range("A2:B"&CStr(LastRow)).Select
```

It search for the last row in column C and uses the value to define what fill.